# Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window--How to find the URl

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this type of question have been asked in different ways. But my question is a bit different.

I have the code to do the form submit and the code to open it in a new window.
But I have one missing piece in here.

I don't know how to generate the complete URL once i have appended the values to request body.The window.open() expects url as the first parameter and i don't know how to retrieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openviewerSelected() {
        var docIds = "{949FFEED-B90B-45DE-BC8A-BDA020D4BCEA}"; 
        if (docIds == null || docIds == "") {
            alert("Select atleast one document");
        }
        else {
            var form = document.createElement("form");

            form.setAttribute("method", "get");
            form.setAttribute("action", "http://aaaa-xxxx.yyyy.com:84/ICNECM/SSOLoginServlet");
            form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

            var input3 = document.createElement('input');
            input3.type = 'hidden';
            input3.name = 'docInfoItems';//'docIds';
            input3.value = docIds;
            form.appendChild(input3);

            var input4 = document.createElement('input');
            input4.type = 'hidden';
            input4.name = "externalUserId";
            input4.value = "abc";
            form.appendChild(input4);

            document.body.appendChild(form);                
            var url = "What should be the value?"//document.body.appendChild(form);
            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (1000 / 2);
            var right = (screen.height / 2) - (600 / 2);
            var specsDetails = 'width=1000,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,left=' + left + ',top=' + right + ',scrollbars=yes';
            window.open(url, '', specsDetails, '');                
            form.submit();
            debugger;
            document.body.removeChild(form);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It feels like there is something missing here, do you want the URL of the current window or do you want another URL? What should the URL be?

Comment: Its not clear to me on why you even need the `document.body.appendChild(form);` code in the first place.  What does that entire paragraph do for you?  You already have a `form.setAttribute("action", URL...`  Although a form with every element hidden from view isn't much of a form...  If hidden from view AND automatically submitted, there are other ways... (ajax calls, curl equivalent submits... etc...)  I see the jQuery tag, the $ajax tool is pretty awesome...

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(form);` if you have appended a form in the current window then what are you trying to open in the popup?

Comment: I don't understand the nature of the problem. Do you want to open the form in a new page, then submit it? Does the form have to open a new page showing the results of the submit? Do you want to consume the results of the submit in a script in a new window?

Comment: @minitauros, Once I have added the input parameter values to the form, I need to get the Url that is getting generated such that i could pass it the window.open() method. With out the window.open() code, It is opening in a new tab. But i want it to open in a new window .i.e. why the specsDetails.

Comment: @Jai I am simply trying to open the generated url (after the form submit) in a new window. i.e why I am trying to pass url value in window.open() method.

Comment: @Shilly I want to show the url in the new window but with the existing code i.e. without the window.open(), I am getting it in a new tab.

Comment: This looks familiar.  Is this for a pron or download movie spam site?

Comment: No offense intended.. but for customers sake, aren't simple AJAX calls a better way to get where you want to go?  When it comes to customer interface, isn't less = more?

Comment: @Ninja see you already submitted your form on current window then why are you bothering to open the same window in other popup window?

Comment: So I'm assuming that the LoginServlet returns you an url that you want to open? Then just using a simple ajax call, as suggested above, instead of a form, would work better. If the servlet returns you a html page instead of a string representing an url, just submitting the form should open the forms result in a new page due to `target="_blank"`. If you have to use a form AND the servlet returns you a url as a string, you'll have to write a script that runs into the window that the form will open, to extract that url from that page.

Comment: @zipzit,Shilly, Jai: Let me try with the ajax call then.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, judging from your comment

> @minitauros, Once I have added the input parameter values to the form, I need to get the Url that is getting generated such that i could pass it the window.open() method. With out the window.open() code, It is opening in a new tab. But i want it to open in a new window .i.e. why the specsDetails.

I would say that you want to open a new window upon form submission instead of a new tab.

If that is the case, consider the following example:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Don't trigger the form submit.

var query_string = input1.name + '=' + input1.value
 + '&' + input2.name + '=' + input2.value
 + '&' + input3.name + '=' + input3.value
 + '&' + input4.name + '=' + input4.value; // etc.
var form_action = this.getAttribute('action');
var url = form_action + '?' + query_string;

// Open your popup.
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (1000 / 2);
var right = (screen.height / 2) - (600 / 2);
var specsDetails = 'width=1000,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,left=' + left + ',top=' + right + ',scrollbars=yes';
window.open(url, '', specsDetails, '');
});
```